# How to pivot rows in SQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a table:

```
   date       Name
2017-02-21    Mark
2017-02-21    Peter
2017-02-21    John
2017-02-22    Mark
2017-02-22    Mark
2017-02-22    Mark
2017-02-22    Peter
```

And I want the following output:

```
    date    Mark  John  Peter
2017-02-21   1      1    1
2017-02-22   3      0    1
```

How can I achieve this in MySQL?

Comment: This is a simple pivot, but note that issues of data display are generally best resolved in the presentation layer, assuming that's available

Comment: @Strawberry regardless where you want to do the pivot, this wuestion is a duplicate, see link

Comment: The duplicate topic describes both static and dynamic pivoting in mysql and provides explanations

Comment: @shadow, regardless, the pivoting should not in my view be done in MySQL

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation to pivot your data like this:

```
select date,
    sum(Name = 'Mark') Mark,
    sum(Name = 'John') John,
    sum(Name = 'Peter') Peter
from your_table
group by date;
```

It uses the fact that MySQL evaluates true to 1 and false to 0.

#### [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/64e74d/1)

Answer (score 1):

use 'FIELD()'

```
select 
sum(field(name,'mark')) as mark,
sum(field(name,'peter')) as peter,
sum(field(name,'john')) as john 
from table_name group by date;
```

Comment: It worked ,ty @denny

Comment: if worked then please accept answer

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly what you want, but you can use `GROUP BY` to group results and then count names, like this:

```
SELECT *,
    COUNT(name) as how_many
FROM your_table
GROUP BY date, name
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/70ebcd/6)